# Isolated debugging session with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm using Eclipse + PyDev to work on python web projects.
Sometimes I need to run debug session on production server rather then locally, due to specific environment.
I was wondering if there is a way to run isolated remote debugging session, so the other users don't experience any issues, and code execution doesn't suspend for them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible out of the box... you'd need to architecture your production server so that this would be possible (i.e.: when you send a given request it should spawn a different interpreter just to handle your request for debugging purposes and shutdown that interpreter after the debug session ends), but you have to make sure that the debugger will actually run in a separate interpreter, otherwise it could end up tracing more things from other people (and in the best situation it'd only make things slower and in the worse it could end up having unexpected consequences because of some interaction of the debugger with your code).